# XAML reference not set to instance of object debugging with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, svg, xamarin

I am builidng a XAML UI, with Xamarin.Forms, using [this](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) nuget plugin. I have followed the guide and have the following layout:

```
   <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#3DBEAF" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="10" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Logo_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   </Grid>
```

I have followed the guide. I don't really see whats happening with the
`SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}"` line, or whether I need to update this? I have followed the sample app's form, by putting my resources in the main PCL project, in an images folder. I have set the build action for these resources, and also initialised the nuget across the platform specific projects as specified.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at SVG.Forms.Plugin.iOS.SvgImageRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e) [0x00028] in :0

What have I done wrong / how can I debug further?

Comment: if you look at the sample app, his ViewModel has a property called SvgAssembly.  You will need to implement that in your VM also

Comment: Also, do you have the abstractions namespace defined in your XAML?

Comment: @Jason Got the namespace definition, but the ViewModel was the problem! Thanks, add an answer and I'll mark it - many thanks!

Comment: @Jason it has now thrown up a new problem ... I have put it up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683540/system-notsupportedexception-svg-element-style-is-not-supported-with-xamarin) if you wanted to have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to SvgAssembly, so you need that defined in your ViewModel.  The sample app defines it like this:

```
public Assembly SvgAssembly
{
    get { return typeof (App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; }
}
```