# System.NotSupportedException: SVG element "style" is not supported with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, svg, xamarin

I am builidng a XAML UI, with Xamarin.Forms, using [this](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) nuget plugin. I have followed the guide and have the following layout:

```
   <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#3DBEAF" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="10" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Logo_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   </Grid>
```

I have followed the guide. However, I get the following error message, what is causing this, and is it something I have done / can fix?

> System.NotSupportedException: SVG element "style" is not supported
>     at NGraphics.Custom.Parsers.SvgReader.AddElement (IList`1 list, System.Xml.Linq.XElement e, NGraphics.Custom.Models.Pen inheritPen, NGraphics.Custom.Models.Brushes.BaseBrush inheritBaseBrush) [0x00577] in :0

Comment: Well, the exception is very clear, the SVG contains a "style" element which that library doesn't support, recreate your SVG's without the style tag or use another library (if there is any).

Comment: Ahh, so I need to change the actual SVG resource ?

Comment: Yep, that library supports an small subset of the SVG specification, so if any of the unsupported tags are found that exception will rise